# How can cofactor matrix help find eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Browsing around for math literature related to eigenvalues and eigenvectors I did not read yet, I came across the following algorithm. It seems to be functional for all 3x3 matrix I tried (symmetric, diagonal, triangular, etc. for a grand total of a few 10000 matrices), but I do not fully get the math logic behind...

Let $M$ be an arbitrary $3 \times 3$ matrix.

Let $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$, and $\lambda_3$ be the eigenvalues of $M$ (i.e.: the roots of its polynomial obtained by solving $det(M - \lambda I) = 0$).

Now, let

$
P = (M - \lambda_{i} I) = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
g & h & i \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

The algorithm then creates three vectors $v_{ij}$ made of the determinant of the sub matrices $M[i,j;]$ as follow:

$
v_{01} = \begin{bmatrix}
   bf - ce  \\
 -(af - cd) \\
   ae - bd  \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

$
v_{02} = \begin{bmatrix}
   bi - ch  \\
 -(ai - cg) \\
   ah - bg  \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

$
v_{12} = \begin{bmatrix}
   ei - fh  \\
 -(di - fg) \\
   dh - eg  \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

From there, we find that the eigenvector associated to the current $\lambda_i$ is the $ \max \left ( |v_{01}|, |v_{021}|, |v_{12}| \right )$ dividing its corresponding vector to produce a normed eigenvector.

**Q1:** Could you explain and provide a bit more details about the math behind this algorithm?

I find some similarities with what I have done by substitution to express one unknown as a function of the others to inject it in a third equation and then solve the system by fixing a free unknown. The above algorithm looks, to me, like a great shortcut to obtain the eigenvectors. Furthermore, when I made my regular calculus there were some "corner cases" to check for in order to avoid, for instance, division by zero.. which seems not to be a problem here!

**Q2:** Although I doubt it, can this adapted to $2 \times 2$?

**Q3:** Can this be extended to higher matrix dimensions?

### EDIT:

Staring at it long enough I realized that the vectors $v_{ij}$ form the rows of the cofactor matrix. I also found out that the odd lines of the cofactor matrix $P$ are timed by -1 (but this does not seem to change the final result).

Now I realize that this can be generalized to higher dimensions matrix (I went up to 5x5).

However, I still don't get the relation so **Q1** is still a question..

**Q4:** why don't we always use this method to compute the eigenvectors? I mean, apart from the higher number of multiplications (which heavily impacts the performance though), this seems to be working for any types of matrix ..

NOTE: I renamed the title of the post accordingly.

Comment: The basic math behind it is the following relation: $ M \text{adj}(M) = \det(M) I $

Comment: So in the case of this problem $P \ \text{adj}(P) = 0 $ where the right-hand side is the $3 \times 3$ zero matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q1.** As we know, the eigenvector $\boldsymbol{v}$ must solve
$$
P\boldsymbol{v}=(M-\lambda I)\boldsymbol{v}=\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
g & h & i \\
\end{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{v}=\boldsymbol{0}\,.
$$
In other words, it must be orthogonal to all three vectors
$$
\boldsymbol{x}=\begin{bmatrix}
a  \\
b \\
c  \\
\end{bmatrix}\,,\quad
\boldsymbol{y}=\begin{bmatrix}
d  \\
e \\
f  \\
\end{bmatrix}\,,\quad
\boldsymbol{z}=\begin{bmatrix}
g  \\
h \\
i  \\
\end{bmatrix}\,.
$$
The existence of a non zero eigenvector is, as we know, equivalent to the matrix $P$ having rank at most two.

If we set $\boldsymbol{v}=\boldsymbol{x}\times\boldsymbol{y}$ (which is exactly what your algorithm is doing) then there are to possibilities:

1. $\boldsymbol{x}$ and $\boldsymbol{y}$ are linearly independent.

   Then $\boldsymbol{v}$ is orthogonal to both, $\boldsymbol{x}$ and $\boldsymbol{y}$. Since $P$ has rank at most two this means that $\boldsymbol{z}$ must be a linear combination of $\boldsymbol{x}$ and $\boldsymbol{y}$. Then *$\boldsymbol{v}$ is orthogonal to all three vectors and therefore an eigenvector.*  $\quad\Box$
2. $\boldsymbol{x}$ and $\boldsymbol{y}$ are not linearly independent.

   Then $\boldsymbol{v}=\boldsymbol{0}$ which is not an eigenvector that we are seeking.

We see that this algorithm does not always produce eigenvectors. The most simple case where it doesn't is $M=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda,\lambda,\lambda)$ in which case $P=0$ and $\boldsymbol{x}=\boldsymbol{y}=\boldsymbol{z}=\boldsymbol{0}\,.$

**Q2. Q3.** Don't think so. The algorithm relies heavily on the properties of the cross product in $\mathbb R^3$.

**Q4.** It should be obvious by now why we don't always use this method.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear and detailed answer. It is now clear as water! One more thing would help: do you mean I got some bad luck when checking against higher dimensions in $R^{n \times n}$? Of course I understand that both diagonal and zero matrices require special handling case, but all other matrices were ok (upper/lower triangular and regular ones)..

Comment: In $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ with $n\not=3$ there is no cross product $\boldsymbol{x}\times\boldsymbol{y}$ that generates a vector. If you have a specific higher dimensional example please post it. We can remove the python code to save some space.

Comment: I just edited the question to add an example of such $4 \ times 4$ matrice

Comment: How did you produce these $4\times 4$ results with a python code that was hardcoded to $3\times 3$ ?   In the meantime I picked up @HosamHajjir 's hint and looked at [Adjugate Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix). The answer to Q3 could then be: It works when you know what determinants you should be calculating.

Comment: I made a generalization based on cofactor for $n \times n$ matrices. Great, so it answers my last question! Thank you very much to the two of you for taking time to answer this post

Comment: I think I concluded too quickly that the algorithm cannot be generalized to $n>3$. Hosam's hint is the way to go. Since you are well versed at programming leave that aside for now. Instead I recommend that you  work out the maths of, say, the $4\times 4$ case just as you described the $3\times 3$ case in the original post.